# What Are The Benefits Of Checking "include android instant app support" CheckBox?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When I Create Anew Project I Found Anew Feature Of Android Studio ,Which Is "include android instant app support" .
Then I Wanna Know What Are The Benefits Of This Feature.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Check the following url

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#app-links

> Both your instant and installable versions of your app must implement
>   the Android App Links feature introduced in Android 6.0. App Links
>   provide the primary mechanism for connecting URLs to discrete
>   activities within your app.
>
> Android Instant Apps uses URLs for all navigation. When a user taps a
>   link to your instant app, they go to a specific activity within your
>   app. If the link fails or the user taps the link on an unsupported
>   device, the browser opens and shows your website.